# css ::before ::after alignment rule

Tags: css

I tried to create a button, with `::before` and `::after` that style it.

If I use absolute positioning(as shown in the part I commented out) it works fine.

But it's interesting that I found `translateY()` not working as I expected and I was not sure why.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin:50px;
  background-color:orangered;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.btn {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 3px;
  width: 4.5rem;
  
  position: relative;
  
  &::before,
  &::after {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 3px;
    width: 4.5rem;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    // left:0;
  }
  
  &::before { transform: translateY(-1rem); }
  &::after { transform: translateY(1rem); }
  
  // &::before { top: -1rem; }
  // &::after { top:  1rem; }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
  <button class="btn">&nbsp;</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Followup:

I edited the question as @ Jacque Goupil suggested. I'll try to make my questions better，still working on it :)

I found that the cross-axis weird positioning was due to the `&nbsp;` that I put in the html (I think `&nbsp;` came with something like `line-height:1` which add addional space vertically). So actually `translateY` works fine, as @Chris Tapay mentioned.

As for the vertical alignment, though the `left:0` solve the problem, it's still a puzzle why they were not aligned initially.

[codepen link](https://codepen.io/sean-bai/pen/daqGyJ?editors=1100)
[image]

Comment: You're not exactly asking a question here. What are you trying to do? How did you expect translateY() to work? And more importantly, users shouldn't have to go on another site to see your code - one day codepen could no longer exist and this question would become unusable. Edit your question taking this into account and you'll find people more eager to help you :)

Comment: @Jacque Goupil thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`translateY` works fine. You may notice it by commenting the `translateY` lines out in your code snippet. Watch the outcome for a second, then uncomment. You will see that they move exactly -1rem and 1rem.

Then, in order to solve the dilemma, you have to set the initial position for both `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements, in which case you'll need:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

Do not rely on browsers default. Remember [CSS resets](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) were created for a reason. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To align both horizontally, add a `left: 0` property, I'm not sure why but the browser calculates `left: 6px`.

Vertically, I'm not sure why you use transform when you are just position absolute position, just set the `:before` at `top: -1rem` and `:after` at `bottom: -1rem`.

Your `translateY` is working ok, the problem is the initial position calculated by the browser.